# listview in android

Tags: android

i need to display four names continues in listview
for example

aravind

bose

guru

moorthy

aravind

bose

guru

moorthy

the set of values to be displayed in listview for "n" number of times
 if i have mension 10times.the four names should be display for 10 times in listview.help me

Comment: can u put a image what type of o/p u want>

Comment: the four names should be display for 10 times in listview

Comment: You  need to do the manipulation in your underlying adaptor. For instance if you have a simple ArrayAdaptor that takes in Array Sequence, duplicate entry in that array before passing on to the array adaptor..

Answer (score 0):

for this you need to pass "n" as a parameter while calling your custom adapter.

Since its your custom adapter create your arrayList in the adapter to be used for the list view using the parameters of ArrayList(data to be displayed) and the "n". Using these create another arrayList which is used to display the listView data..

the call would be somewhat like this:

listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_view,
                countryStringList, n);